# How close does the Call of Cthulhu (2005 movie) stick to the novel?

Tags: adaptation-comparison, cthulhu-mythos, the-call-of-cthulhu, the-call-of-cthulhu-2005

There has recently been a [highly acclaimed adaptation](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0478988/) of HP Lovecraft's novel, The Call of Cthulhu. I'm very interested in this movie as I've loved the novel, but I wondered how closely this movie stuck to the novel's story and style?

Comment: You can watch the movie for free on imdb.com so you can see for yourself lol. It's only 45 mins long.

Comment: @OghmaOsiris Uh, how?

Comment: If you look up the movie at imdb, there will be a section for videos and one will be labeled full movie.

Comment: @OghmaOsiris you mean this: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0478988/videogallery ? I only see two trailers. I'm in the UK.

Comment: Hmm I didn't think about the UK bit.

Comment: You can see the whole movie on youtube. The 2005 adaptation is a shortmovie that is well worth seeing.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qk-hKmWNP8g&feature=BFa&list=PL12C409E928A0DC9E&lf=results_main

Comment: I love that movie version, bought it from them and tried to help a bit with their next feature.

Answer (score 4):

Movie and novel are fairly close: both keep to the same "[frame story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_story)" style (story within a story within a story) with [German Expressionism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_Expressionism) as a movie tool to replace Lovecraft original writing style (so you have actors overacting emotions when they encounter "blasphemous, cyclopean, unnamed shapes that could not exist!").

Story in both cases is almost identical with few differences:

> The sailors aboard the Emma first encounter the Alert abandoned at sea, rather than crewed by Cthulhu cultists and taken over by Emma's crew after a violent confrontation as in the original story. Additionally, the film depicts the narrator present at the time of his great-uncle's death, who dies peacefully in his sleep, rather than being summoned upon the mysterious death of his great-uncle, who was presumably killed by Cthulhu cultists in the original short story. The narrator (Matt Foyer) notes that Inspector Legrasse, who had directed the raid on cultists in backwoods Louisiana, died before the narrator's investigation began.
>
> In the original story, the narrator does not seem to end in a lunatic asylum or experience any mysterious nightmares himself.
> [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Call_of_Cthulhu_(film))

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't, really.  As with most adaptations of Lovecraft, what makes a good screenplay is also NOT what makes an HP Lovecraft story.  It doesn't seem at all like the story, I didn't even see the scene where they were rolling dice and noticed boxcars every time.  They are different stories altogether.

Comment: To say they are different stories altogether is preposterous. The young man inherit's his uncle's box, wherein he finds three things that lead to a recounting of all parts, "The Horror in Clay," "The Tale of Inspector Legrasse," and "The Madness from the Sea." It's all there. Some concessions were made for adaptation, particularly in the last part, where ships are combined to expedite the story, but it's very faithful.